# asymptotics of Involutions recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Consider the following recurrence relation where $t(n)$ is the number of involutions on $\{1,...,n\}$

\begin{equation}
(n+1)t(n)+t(n+1)-t(n+2)=0
\end{equation}

When $n \rightarrow \infty$, Wimp and Zeilberger have found the asymptotics as (on page 8 in http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.145.7385&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

\begin{equation}
t(n) \propto  (\frac{n}{e})^{\frac{n}{2}} e^{\sqrt n} \{1+\frac{c_{1}}{\sqrt n}+\frac{c_{2}}{n}+....\}
\end{equation}

Then they claim that:" It is easy to find $c_{1}=\frac{7}{24}$ and also to determine $c_{2}, c_{3},...$" without any explanation. How can one find out the values of $c_{1}, c_{2},...$?

Comment: The coefficient 7/24 is given in the reference of Knuth cited by Wimp and Zeilberger (section 5.1.4 in volume 3), but the computations are quite involved.

Comment: @Michael ugo: No! Knuth is using a different technique in order to find the asymptotics. Wimp uses Birkhoff series. He finds the form of the asymptotics first and then figures out what the $c$'s are. He doesn't explain how he finds them though, just says that "it's easy!". The final result of the two approaches, of course, is the same.

Comment: Looks like you read that section of Knuth more carefully than me. I stand corrected.